# How to add an existing kubernetes pod as a jenkins node.?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-on-premises

Is there any way to add a existing pod or create a new pod in kubernetes and attach as jenkins node.?

We can create dynamic pods using kubernetes plugin using plugin settings and yaml provided in pipeline. When pipeline is started the pod get created and get destroyed once completed. Also we can create as external IP service for pod and use it as a node. Both the ways wont work for my case as the pods are need to be created by another tool which masks lot of underlying specs from user. Kubectl plugin and through kubectl exec cant also be used since the job using passphrase, user inputs etc

The problem statement:

Use the existing pod as an agent in jenkins.
Or create new pod with jnlp, jenkins secret etc which when created will connect to jenkins as node
Once the pod is running as an agent then commands can be executed from pipeline.

I tried one way of getting the yaml out of running jenkins node created with kubernetes plugin and creating it manualy [the pod yaml have all details of jenkins instace, secrets, jnlp/inbound agent etc]. But it was not able to run as expected.

create a pod --> attach as Jenkins node --> execute scripts/commands

Any help or lead on this will be great!

Create jenkins slave with kubernetes plugin.
describe with -o yaml for pod yaml.
applied the yaml for creating new pod which expected to attach as slave, but pod shown connection error etc